# neo4j add relations to nodes with similar properties

Tags: python, python-2.7, neo4j

I have DB and I want to connect all nodes with equal properties. For example:

```
node("name"="Bob","age":"32")
node("name"="cherry","age":"32")
```

I want to make relation `"age"` between two nodes. How It can be done?
I use `py2neo` python module.
Many thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about properties or labels? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Properties, sorry. Editing now.

Comment: it's still not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to create a node for age:32, and connect the other two nodes to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but for a very general solution you can try a cypher query like this (2.0 syntax)

```
MATCH n, m 
WHERE n<>m AND n.age = m.age AND NOT (n-[:AGE]->m) 
CREATE n-[r:AGE]->m 
RETURN r
```

This will take each node and look for any other node that has the same value for property `age` and create a relationship `[:AGE]` to that node. It checks that the node in question doesn't already have such a relationship to the other node, so you won't get duplicates if you run it again (but it does create the relationship in both directions) and it also checks that the other node is not the same as the first, so it won't create the relationship from a node to itself. If you want to do the same for a different property you can just substitute that property name for `age` and set a different type for the relationship.

Since you didn't specify your requirements, I think this answers your question. You can also implement this in python code, and if that's what you want to do maybe you can show what you have tried so far (the snippet in your question doesn't look like valid python). A suggestion there might be to consider indexing your nodes on the relevant property so when you have a node like `(Bob {age:32})` you can look up all other nodes with the same value for age, iterate through the results and create the relationships, rather than iterate through all nodes in the db every time. The same goes for Cypher, labels and indexing would improve performance on a real data set, but the query above illustrates a way in which it can be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was exactly what I needed! Only one more small question, I have to use START before MATCH (version 1.9) how I can ignore nodes where property 'age' doesnt exist?

Comment: Read the docs for the `WHERE`, for instance http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html#where-property-exists